# Setting direction to right to left on Excel 2011 on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I am using Excel 2011 on a Mac and would like my Excel worksheets to be right to left.

I am trying for a long time already and can't find a solution.

How can I do it?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/my-office-mac-2011-cant-support-rtl-languages-need/f6353ae3-feb8-4e40-a6b5-61aa679967d9 http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/readonly/does-microsoft-office-for-mac-2011-support-arabic/QF9F7P7PAHFY9DK2F

Answer (score 0):

You can try Page Layout Tab, Sheet Options Group, Sheet Right to Left Command